# Определение констант в проекте Define Constant

Tags: c#, .net-core

Есть 2 проекта. Вложенный проект имеет 2 модели: `Model1in` и `Model1Out`.

```
namespace Test.Nested
{
    public class Model1in
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1in(Model1Out model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1in();
        }
#endif
    }

    public class Model1Out
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1Out(Model1in model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1Out();
        }
#endif     
}
```

В другом проекте я хочу привести одну модель к другой но с указанием директивы.

```
#define NATIVE

namespace Test.Native
{
     ....
     Model1Out model = (Model1Out)Model1in;
}
```

Компилятор возвращает ошибку и не видит описание метода, которое было реализовано с директивой. Пробовал делать описывать открытый метод но с разными результатами для каждой из директив - все равно берет значение без директив. Также добавлял в проект.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;NATIVE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors />
    <DefineConstants>NATIVE;Release</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <DefineConstants>RELEASE;DEBUG;NATIVE</DefineConstants>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;NATIVE</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: а без директивы он его видит? Потому что по приведенному фрагменту могу предположить что ваш метод не будет виден даже если убрать все директивы условной компиляции, а это значит где-то забыта ссылка на проект или сборку

Comment: @rdorn сам метод без директивы норм видит, но во с ней - никак. 
Сделал внутрь метода директиву, но это лишь дает возможность запускать билд, не более. Как не видело константы кастомные, так и не видит во внутреннем проекте. Хотя и во внешнем тоже.

Comment: Так у вас константа в другой сборке определена? Нет, так работать не будет, директивы препроцессора работают в пределах одной сборки, т.к. каждая сборка проекта компилируется независимо.

Comment: @rdorn Она определена в обеих сборках. 
Самый простой вариант как я хотел сделать: к примеру есть 2 верси netcore2_1 и netcore2_2. В основной (external project) я реализую для обоих версих (параметров), а в других двух проектах использую только ту, какая указана версия. Но это работает только с версиями, документации по кастомным параметрам я так и не нашел. На сайте мелкомягких в документации, к сожалению, многого нет. Вот думал может у его есть какие-то tricks по этой теме или может кто знает, где хотябы найти доки в большем виде.

Answer (score -2):

На сколько я понял, Ваш проект Test.Nested не знает ничего о "NATIVE"
Оставив код как есть в этом классе

```
namespace Test.Nested
{
    public class Model1in
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1in(Model1Out model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1in();
        }
#endif
    }

    public class Model1Out
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1Out(Model1in model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1Out();
        }
#endif     
}
```

но определив констаннты в проекте (*.csproj)

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NATIVE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Вы позволяете ему работать с ними.

Эту же констатнту Вы должны объявить в первом проекте, где используете преоброзование (Test.Native).

Вот только код

```
#define NATIVE

namespace Test.Native
{
     ....
     Model1Out model = (Model1Out)Model1in;
}
```

имеет ошибку. Вы можете преоброзовать объект, а не его тип

```
 var test = new Model1in();
      Model1Out model = (Model1Out)test;
```

**UPDATE**: Полный пример:

**Test.Nested** определяем NATIVE

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NATIVE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Конвертер:

```
namespace Test.Nested
{
    public class Model1in
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1in(Model1Out model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1in();
        }
#endif
    }

    public class Model1Out
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1Out(Model1in model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1Out();
        }
#endif     
}
```

**Test.Native** определяем NATIVE для второго проекта

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NATIVE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\Test.Nested.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Активируем NATIVE (ставим значени в true):

```
#define NATIVE
using System;
using Test.Nested;

namespace Test.Native
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var test = new Model1in();
      var model = (Model1Out)test;
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: про ошибку. Там опечатка. Выдавал данные для примера.
Про оба проекта - будьте внимательны. Мы это уже обсудили в комментариях ранее.

Comment: @sombik прочитайте еще раз внимательно мой ответ. Директивы должны быть объявлены в обоих (Test.Nested.csproj и Test.Native.csproj) проектах. Атикируте(#define NATIVE) вы ей в первом, с этого момента вторая видит, что #if NATIVE = true и позволяет сделать конвертацию. Это все, что у Вас неправильно

Comment: вот, посмотрите, не всё так просто, как Вам кажется.
https://github.com/ykavalenka/define_test

Comment: @sombik Извините, но я уже в Ваших примерах запутался. В первом говорить о том, что не видит метод преобразования, в github  у Вас пример, почему при входе в метод преобразования у вас не выбирается нужное преобразование. (if native.. elseif native_lambda.. ) При  первоначальном вопросе, настаиваю, что у вас они не были видны проекту-конвертору, их примера на GitHub поясняю, что Ваш define работает совсем не так, как считаете. Define.Data.csproj говорит, что оба параметра одинаково true. Вы это опять это говорите в Models.cs первыми строчкачми.

Comment: Увы, но вариант с просто DefineConstant не работает. Даже, для примера, попробовал и другие вариации - ничего. Единственный вариант, как можно реализовать подобное, но, это совсем бред, вместо кастомных Define использовать константы версий. Например netcore, netstandart и прочее. И, в зависимости от версии билда, уже реализовывать функционал. Но это совсем не хороший подход, я бы даже сказал - ужасный. Найти литературу по передаче DefineConstant в проект одной сборки с разными наборами констант так и не удалось.

Comment: @sombik это правильный подход но не надо привязыватся к платформе. Вся эта конитель используется для построение приложения под различные варанты выполнения. Через DefineConstant вы говорите, что доступно проекту, через msbuild / dotnet build вы указываете конфигурацию: dev, beta, debug, mobile..  msbuild генерит код под данную конфигурацию и вы получаете нужную вам логику native, native_lambda... Это всё.

Comment: Да, Вы безусловно правы. Именно на примере платформы я и хотел сделать. Только с использованием констант, которые определены в самой сборке сразу. Без билда нескольких версий. Увы, как показала практика, такое не совсем возможно. Все равно необходимо иметь либо хитрое включение констант внутрь одной сборки и управление ими (материалов по этой теме я не нашел в достаточном количестве), или делать отдельные сборки под каждую конфигурацию билда.